# Select2 Dropown in Handsontable goes out of layout/cell

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-select2, handsontable

Please check the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/rajivseelam/zfmdu4wt/5/

I am using select2 3.5.2 and handsontable latest.

To add select2 dropdown to handsontable, I used plugin at https://github.com/trebuchetty/Handsontable-select2-editor

Steps to see the issue:

1. Click on an empty cell under Cost column, it shows a dropdown with options fixed and variable.[image]
2. Click again on the same cell, it shows dropdown but it goes out of cell.[image]

The following control the dropdown in handsontable:

```
        {
          data: 'cost',
          editor: 'select2', 
          renderer: customDropdownRenderer,
          select2Options: { 
                  data: [{id:'fixed',text:'Fixed'},{id:'variable',text:'Variable'}] ,
                  dropdownAutoWidth: true,
          }
        },
```

I have been trying to fix this problem, but I couldn't. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The select-drop element seems to be getting inline styles so I assume the Javascript is injecting CSS code to that box, you could edit it using jQuery by doing some calculations.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to do that. I am not table to think of calculations as it was working fine the first time. There is a method in Select2 positionDropdown, in which container.offset() changes when clicked the second time.

Comment: Well, I tried reproducing your example with the original files from cdnjs.com and it didn't work so i'm not sure :P

Comment: You mean when you used original files, issue didn't occur? Would you please tell me which files did you change? Is it just Select2 3.5.2?

Comment: No, it didn't work, i'm trying again.

Comment: Where did you get this `select2-editor.js`? In any case, I tried it locally and it works. http://jsfiddle.net/zfmdu4wt/15/

Comment: I mentioned in question also, I took it from here: https://github.com/trebuchetty/Handsontable-select2-editor, In the jsFiddle you gave there is no Select2 added, so it's not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82458/discussion-between-rjvim-and-odedta).

Comment: Yeah, I cannot find it online...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try commenting the following line
this.$textarea.offset($(this.TD).offset());
in the select2-editor.js (Select2Editor.prototype.open function)

Comment: This is the correct answer. I've merged this change into the master branch of the editor.